# How to capture multiline regex between two tags that are into different steps/array/place

Tags: php, regex, tags, tcpdf

I Use TCPDF for generate some complex PDF so the problem is inside a PDF not into a standard web page

I'm trying to get text between 2 tags including the two tags that are: `[#SCHANGE#]` and `[#ECHANGE#]`.

I'm using this regex:

```php
preg_match('/(?:\[#SCHANGE#\]((?:.*?\r?\n?)*)\[#ECHANGE#\])+/m', $textV, $StartEndChange);
```

`$textV` is a dynamic value that came from a foreach loop like:

```php
foreach($text as $textV){

    //some code here..

}
```

and inside there can be different situations such as:

```php
$text = array (
    "0" => "[#SCHANGE#] same text [#ECHANGE#]" //This is okay, regex works in this case
) ;
```

But this regex is not working when in `$text` there is only one tag then i have this situation :

```php
$text = array (
    "0" => "[#SCHANGE#]same text",
    "1" => "some text",
    "2" => "some text",
    "3" => "some text",
    "4" => "some text",
    "5" => "some text",
    "6" => "some text",
    "7" => "some text [#ECHANGE#]"
) ;
```

So: how i can get the text between 2 tags including the two tags if the tags are not in the same text?

I can't explode the array bacause all the text inside `$text` is formatted and can be print differently from the previous or next one

Comment: Are you doing this on a string with new lines on an array where each line is a separate string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$re = '/(\[#SCHANGE#\](.+?)\[#ECHANGE#\])|(\[#SCHANGE#\](.+?$))|(^(.+?)\[#ECHANGE#\])/m';

$str = '[#SCHANGE#]same text
some text [#ECHANGE#]
[#SCHANGE#] same text [#ECHANGE#]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

**RegEx**

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uPtb5a/1/).

Comment: @Nunzio Marfè: This working only for a string, not for an array as you've given in your question.

Comment: Okay thanks that's what i needed! this make me able to get the tags and text even if there is one or the other.

Comment: @Toto the array is in a loop, so I assumed that he goes to process the single string

Comment: @toto If you read, in the preg_match there is $textV not $text, so the preg_match is into the loop and the value that the function analyze is like the string that Nerdvoso tested.

Comment: @NunzioMarfè: It doesn't match all the elements that are in your array `$text`, it matches only the first and the last one, your question was: "how i can get the text between 2 tags including the two tags if the tags are not in the same text?".

Answer (score 2):

I'd do first implode the array then search in the string:

```
$text = array (
    "[#SCHANGE#]same text",
    "some text",
    "some text",
    "some text",
    "some text",
    "some text",
    "some text",
    "some text [#ECHANGE#]",
    "blah blah",
    "[#SCHANGE#]other text[#ECHANGE#]"
) ;

$all_text = implode("\n", $text);
preg_match_all('/\[#SCHANGE#\][\s\S]+?\[#ECHANGE#\]/', $all_text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [#SCHANGE#]same text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text
some text [#ECHANGE#]
            [1] => [#SCHANGE#]other text[#ECHANGE#]
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original expression is quite close. We might just want to take `(\[#SCHANGE#\])` and `(\[#ECHANGE#\])` as left and right boundaries, then collect our "some text", maybe with an expression similar to:

```
(\[#SCHANGE#\])(.+?)(\[#ECHANGE#\])
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(\[#SCHANGE#\])(.+?)(\[#ECHANGE#\])/m';
$str = '[#SCHANGE#] same text 1 [#ECHANGE#]
[#SCHANGE#] same text 2 [#ECHANGE#]
[#SCHANGE#] same text 3 [#ECHANGE#]
[#SCHANGE#] same text 4 [#ECHANGE#][#SCHANGE#] same text 5 [#ECHANGE#]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$arr = array();
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {$arr[$key] = $value[0];}
var_dump($arr);
```

#### Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(35) "[#SCHANGE#] same text 1 [#ECHANGE#]"
  [1]=>
  string(35) "[#SCHANGE#] same text 2 [#ECHANGE#]"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "[#SCHANGE#] same text 3 [#ECHANGE#]"
  [3]=>
  string(35) "[#SCHANGE#] same text 4 [#ECHANGE#]"
  [4]=>
  string(35) "[#SCHANGE#] same text 5 [#ECHANGE#]"
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9YjF10/1/).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This make me able only when both tags are into the string